# What is the number of real roots of the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The number of distinct real roots of the equation

$x^9+x^7+x^5+x^3+x+1=0.$

Comment: no Sir....But I want to solve it without using graph.

Comment: $$1+x+x^3+x^5+x^7+x^9=\left(\frac{x^{10}-1}{x^2-1}\right)x+1$$ might be helpful...

Comment: I ask about whether you know anything about the graph, because this is the way I grew my knowledge of how functions work. There is some sophisticated machinery for finding the number of roots in a general case. Here you are adding simple powers of $x$ - and, for example, $x^9$ is an increasing function. What happens when you add increasing functions together?

Comment: plotting this will indicate -0.620374 is the root if you need it for practical purposes.

Answer (score 11):

Let $f(x)=x^9+x^7+x^5+x^3+x+1$, then $f^\prime (x)=9x^8+7x^6+5x^4+3x^2+1\geq1>0.$ Hence $f$ is strictly increasing, so has atmost one real root. Also $f(0)=1>0$ and $f(-1)=-4<0$ and so has a root between $-1$ and $0$.